# Whether a ring extension can be both algebraic and transcendental

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R$ and $R'$ be rings and $R$ be a subring of $R'.$ For simplicity we require that $R$ and $R'$ to be commutative with unity, and $R,R'$ share the same unity(multiplicative identity element). In addition assume that there exists an element $w$ such that $R'=R[w]:=\{a_0+a_1w+\cdots+a_nw^n|\ n\geq 0,\ a_i\in R\}.$

**Question:** Is it possible that one can find two elements $u,v\in R'$ such that $u$ algberaic over $R,$ $v$ transcendental over $R,$ and such that
\begin{equation}\boxed{R'=R[u]=R[v]}?\tag{1}\end{equation}

**Remark:** Of course, if $R$ is an integral domain, then the case $(1)$ never happens, according to the properties of polynomial rings over integral domains. But **how about the general case that $R$ may have zero divisors**? It is quite plausible that one can construct some strange ring $R$ such that $R'=R[u]=R[v]$ is simultaneously an algebraic and transcendental simple extension of $R.$ Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "simple ring extension"?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak: Basically it means that there exists an element $u\in R'$ such that $R'=R[u]=\{a_0+a_1 u+\cdots+a_n u^n|\ n\geq 0, a_i\in R\}.$

Comment: Can you tell me where you found this particular definition?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak: It's an extension of the concept of "simple field extension", maybe just coined by me, I'm sorry for the confusion caused and I'll edit the post.

Comment: Ok. When you say algebraic, do you mean integral or something else?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak: $u\in R'$ is said to be algebraic over $R,$ if there exists $a_0,\cdots,a_n\in R$ such that $a_n\neq 0$ and $a_0+a_1u+\cdots+a_nu^n=0.$  In this general definition, no specific assumptions on the properties of $R$ and $R'$ are made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no such $R$. We claim that if, for a ring $R$ and $p(x)\in R[x]$, the $R$-endomorphism $f$ of $R[x]$ which sends $x$ to $p(x)$ is surjective, then it is in fact isomorphism. This shows that if $R’$ is generated by a transcendental element over $R$, then any other generating element cannot be algebraic in your sense.

Proof of the claim: There exists a ring extension $\tilde{R}\supset R$ where $p(x)$ has a root $\alpha $ in $\tilde{R}$: Set $\tilde{R}=R[y]/(p(y))$ and choose a $q(y)$ such that $q(p(y))=y$. It is immediate that $\alpha:=y\in \tilde{R}$ is a root of $p$. The morphism $y\mapsto q(y)$ induces $R[y]/(p(y))\to R[y]/(y)=R$, which is identity on $R$. In particular $R\hookrightarrow \tilde {R}$ is inclusion.

Tensoring $f$ with $\tilde{R}$ over $R$, we obtain $\tilde{f}:\tilde{R}[x]\to\tilde{R}[x]$. Since $R[x]$ is a free module, $f$ is injective if and only if $\tilde{f}$ is injective. Composing the isomorphism $x\mapsto x+\alpha$ after $\tilde{f}$, we get a surjective endomorphism $\tilde{g}$ of $\tilde{R}[x]$ which sends $x$ to $p(x+\alpha)=a_1x+\dots +a_nx^n$.

$a_1$ is a unit of $\tilde{R}$: if it was contained in a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, then $\tilde{g}$ mod $\mathfrak{m}$ would send $x$ to $b_2x^2+\dots + b_nx^n$, contradicting the fact $\tilde{g}$ is surjective (its image would not contain $x$).

Let $c_0+\dots+c_mx^m$ be in the kernel of $\tilde{g}$. Then we can see inductively $c_0=\dots=c_m=0$, i.e. $\tilde{g}$ is injective.

Comment: Nice! I don't need to waste my efforts trying to construct a strange ring anymore!  By the way, I think that the proof can be simplified: if $p(x)$ generates $R[x],$ then the endomorphism $f:R[x]\to R[x],\ x\mapsto p$ that extend the identity on $R$ is surjective, and there exists a polynomial $q(x)\in R[x]$ such that $q(p(x))=x,$ hence the endomorphism $g:R[x]\to R[x],\ x\mapsto q$ that extend the identity on $R$ is also surjective, since $p\in \mathrm{Im}(g).$ Note that $f\circ g(x)=f(q)=q(p(x))=x,$ hence $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_{R[x]},$ which proves that $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: @painday Could you explain why $p\in \operatorname{Im}g$?

Comment: Sorry, I confused the action of $f$ and $g$ at that moment. It turns out that my argument is incorrect.

Comment: @painday It happens to the best of us. :)

Comment: I have not learned about the concept of "tensoring $f$ with $\tilde R$ over $R$". Could you please elaborate on it a bit? Thanks！\(‵▽′)/

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** this is only a partial answer which shows that a possible counterexample needs to be non-reduced.

To demonstrate that such a situation doesn't occur, it suffices to show that if $u$ is algebraic, then every element of $R[u]$ is algebraic over $R$.

Let $a_nu^n+\dots+a_1u+a_0=0$, then if we localize at $s:=a_n$, we get that $\frac{u}{1} \in R[u]_s$ is integral over $R_s$. By abuse of notation, let's call $\frac{u}{1}$ also $u$. Now $R_s[u]/R_s$ is finite. It's not difficult to see that $R_s[u]=R[u]_s$ We have a morphism $R[u] \to R[u]_s$ given by $b \mapsto \frac{b}{1}$.

Because $\frac{b}{1}$ is integral over $R_s$, we find that $\alpha_0+\alpha_1\frac{b}{1}+\dots+\frac{b^m}{1}=\frac{0}{1}$ for some $\alpha_i \in R_s$. Now we can choose an $N$ large enough so that $s^N\alpha_i = \frac{w_i}{1}$ for some $w_i \in R$ and $w_m=s^N$. Then $$\frac{w_0+w_1b+\dots+s^Nb^m}{1}=\frac01$$

Using the definition of equality in a localization, this implies that for some $k \in \Bbb N$

$$s^k(w_0+w_1b+\dots+s^Nb^m)=0$$ Now we are done unless $s^{k+N}=0$. I'm not sure how to deal with the case that $s$ is nilpotent. In that case, the localization used above doesn't yield anything useful.